# std::bad_alloc with a very large hexadecimal address location

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I have a program that allocates memory using the code,

```
data[0] = new T[column_size.back() + 1];
```

data is declared as

```
T ** data;
```

It does work for while but after 6500 iterations, it gives this error,

```
std::bad_alloc
[i05-007:21393] *** Process received signal ***
[i05-007:21393] Signal: Aborted (6)
[i05-007:21393] Signal code:  (-6)
[i05-007:21393] [ 0] /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x74)[0xffffffff1330a534]
[i05-007:21393] [ 1] /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x168)[0xffffffff1330bc14]
```

I tried to use the try-catch block to check the memory address of data[0]

```
try {
   data[0] = new T[column_size.back() + 1];
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
   cerr << "Iteration " << iter << ": data[0] is at " << data[0] << endl;
   cerr << e.what() << endl;
   abort();
}
```

First I get some normal hex address locations, e.g.

```
iteration 6498: data[0] is at 0xa267aec0
iteration 6499: data[0] is at 0xa26c9f70
```

At iteration 6500, the code produces the bad_alloc error and the catch prints out the memory location of data[0] which is a very large number if converted to decimal.

```
iteration 6500: data[0] is at 0xffffffff12a57310
```

Is there any explanation for this or is it because this is already in the catch block that's why it returns this address? I am wondering if this is in fact a valid address or not. I tried to convert it to decimal and it is 18446744069727417104 which is quite large.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want a valid value use nothrow.

Comment: Hi stark, what do you mean by "If you want a valid value use not grow"? Thanks.

Comment: That was auto-correct.

Comment: Got it. I also tried that but it just gives me the bad_alloc error. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Posted it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @NikkiMino *Posted it. Sorry about that.* -- Where is the `main` function?  You're supposed to post something that runs.

Comment: You are printing out an uninitialized object

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't think posting something that runs is possible as the program has literally hundreds of thousand of lines of code. This particular template is just used to "pack" a very large data into a 2d vector for MPI communication. I am sorry for such inconvenience. Currently, I just believe that it might be lack of memory but I was wondering why return a very large hex number.

Comment: *I don't think posting something that runs is possible as the program has literally hundreds of thousand of lines of code* -- I could easily break your program in 3 lines of code.  The reason -- lack of a user-defined assignment operator for `HVector2D`.  Also, you can turn off copying at compile time -- there is no need for a runtime check for copying, as your code is doing now.  Last, why are you mixing raw pointers with vector usage?  Why not go all the way with using `vector`?

Comment: Have you considered just using a vector of vectors for the data?

Comment: Hi M.M, I wanted to consider that but this code is written by a team and unfortunately I don't decide what to use. My current task is just to debug why this happens. Thanks.

Comment: @NikkiMino Then your team needs to complete the class by providing an assignment operator for your class. `int main() { HVector2D v1(1, {0}); HVector2D v2; v2 = v1;}` -- instantly broken.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the suggestion about copying, I will try to raise that point with our team. I am not entirely sure of the reason why raw pointers are being mixed with vectors but I don't have the option to change it. Thank you.

Comment: Also, there is no need to check for `nullptr` when issuing a call to `delete` or `delete[]`.  Maybe some of your team should invest in reading books by Scott Meyers or other C++ experts, as there are a lot of holes in the code you're showing us that a seasoned C++ professional shouldn't or wouldn't make.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your advice. :)